# Mobile synchronization framework between two databases

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-cognito

I'm building a mobile application and I've reached the point in which I need to deal with data synchronization between my mobile app and a central server.

I've been investigating about mobile synchronization frameworks (like [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), [Couchbase Mobile](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-mobile), [Red Hat Data Sync Framework](http://docs.feedhenry.com/v3/guides/sync_service.html)) but I'm not sure which one to use!!! :(

I need to keep user's data (stored in a local database within the device, like SQLite) synchronized with his data in a central server (stored in a local database within the server, like PostgreSQL). Somewhat like **database synchronization/replication**.

I've been trying out with Cognito first:
I've managed to test some of its sample apps, read some documentation, and see some examples, but I haven't found any example, guide or tutorial about how to replicate data between my two databases. Even, inside Cognito's configuration I can't find any section or configuration that points to a database connection of my choice.
Because of this, now I'm not sure if this can be achieved using Cognito.

Any ideas of which famework/API you recommend me to use???
Any ideas how can I solve or implement a solution for this issue???
Or do I have to make some extra programming on the device side and server side, to somewhat like "catch" this data and store it in its corresponding database???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally possible with Cognito sync, there are two ways of doing this. One way is [Cognito events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-events.html), which lets you get any dataset update in a lambda function, with which you can do whatever you please. The other is twofold: [Cognito streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-streams.html), which puts every sync update into a kinesis stream to consume as you please (see [the blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx35782XTJZROY4/Announcing-Amazon-Cognito-Streams) for an end to end example), and the bulk publish API, which puts every record into a kinesis stream at once for consumption on an ad hoc basis.